# How to "internationalize" Play Framework 2.1 routes?

Tags: internationalization, routes, playframework-2.1

I am using Play Framework 2.1, and I would like to create routes that depend on the user language.

For example, to access the login page, an English speaker could type "mywebsite.com/login", and a French speaker "mywebsite.com/connexion".

Is there any way to do something like:

```
GET     /messages("url.login")    controllers.Application.login()
```

using the play.i18n.Messages library?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible with common routing.

On the other hand, you will need t write custom action which will 'catch' all not defined routes and will try to fit them to some rulez of your own.